# Render output of print(data.tree) to the UI in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have output of data.tree package as follows in the console :

```
print(acme, "cost", "p")

#Out of Data.tree print JPEG
```

[image]

I want to render the same output structure in the shiny UI.

I have tried paste(console.output(print(acme, "cost", "p")),collapse = "
"), but the output structure is not same.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
          sliderInput(inputId = "slider", 
          label = "My number", 
          min = 300, 
          max = 19000,
          value = 5000),
          htmlOutput("mytext")
                   )

server <- function(input, output) {
          output$mytext <- renderText({
          paste(capture.output(print(acme, "cost", "p")),collapse = "<br/>")
       })
       }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Please suggest me any render functions , that will print the output exactly like the above in the Shiny UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL:DR; Replace `renderText()` with `renderPrint()` in server and `htmlOutput()` with `verbatimTextOutput()` in ui.

The issue is with how `renderText()` works. It concatenates all the text input with `cat()` which will fail when using against the data.tree object,  which is a list. You should use [`renderPrint()`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderPrint.html) to capture the output of your print statement. No `capture.output()` required. The `renderPrint()` will not work with various output methods, the safest one to use is `verbatimTextOutput()`. I base that recommendation from experimentation, not actual documentation research. htmlOutput might work but I an not sure.

Updated code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
          sliderInput(inputId = "slider", 
          label = "My number", 
          min = 300, 
          max = 19000,
          value = 5000),
          verbatimTextOutput("mytext")
                   )

server <- function(input, output) {
          output$mytext <- renderPrint({
          print(acme, "cost", "p"))
       })
       }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```